# Use of “short” in sentence

Tags: adjectives

> Money you sent turned out $10 short.

Let’s say that someone said me that he sent me $100 but in an envelope. But the money he sent was $90 . Can i use “short” as is the case with sentence above.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **short** in this case means "not reaching the desired amount." You can use it in a sentence like you've provided, but personally I'd phrase it slightly differently:

> The money you sent turned out to be $10 short.

Or simply:

> The money you sent was $10 short.